# Poor performance during "Who Dares Wins"

Tags: technical-issues, fallout-3, performance

I've been playing Fallout 3 GOTY edition (via Steam). So far the game has been relatively well-behaved - good performance, and only an occasional crash (like once every 3 hours, which is something I can live with).

However, in the recent hour or so it has became worse; in particular, every time I open a container the game freezes for around a second, and crashing becomes much more frequent, around once every 15 or 30 minutes.

I am a level 30 character working on the Broken Steel "Who Dares Wins" quest, which is the quest where

> you assault the Adams Air Force base, fighting outdoors in the unique area opened by the quest, and inside the huge crawler.

And I think it might have been related. I also have a bunch of stuff in my inventory, but not more than what I've been carrying throughout the rest of game (though I do carry more weapons and less armor than what I used to).

Is this a known issue? Any idea how to solve this problem?

System is Windows 7 64-bit, 4 GB RAM, Core 2 Duo.

Comment: In general, the best idea in a Bethesda game when you start experiencing all kinds of nastiness is to wait somewhere for ~2 weeks - this resets all cells (rooms) that you are not currently in.

Comment: @agent86 that sounds like a brilliant tip, but unfortunately that is not possible during that quest, as far as I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've suspected, after the completion of the quest the performance became normal again. I could not find a solution other than saving really frequently :(